# Sort elements by name in a list

Tags: r

If I have a list like so:

```
test_100 = data.frame(rnorm(10),rnorm(10))
test_40 = data.frame(rnorm(10),rnorm(10))
test_20 = data.frame(rnorm(10),rnorm(10))
test_50 = data.frame(rnorm(10),rnorm(10))

mylist = list(test_100,test_40,test_50,test_20)
names(mylist)=c('test_100','test_40','test_20','test_50')
```

and I wanted to order the items from lowest to highest (i.e `test_20` , `test_40`,`test_50`,`test_100`), how would I do this?

The purpose of this is because the data.frames above will be passed through grid.arrange and I want the plots to be in order from lowest to highest. I'm trying to make the code as generic as possible in case there are more then 4 data.frames in that list.

I could try something like:

`as.numeric(gsub('.*?(\\d+)','\\1',names(mylist)))` to extrace the number but how would I then sort based on this?

Comment: Something like`s = as.numeric(unlist(strsplit(names(mylist), "_"))[seq(2, 8, 2)]); mylist[order(s)]`

Comment: Justin, Roland's link works perfectly `mylist[mixedorder(names(mylist))]`

Comment: Ah, yup. sorry! I implemented wrong on my end. Thanks to all!